# Crash on iOS9 when I use xcode10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10

Recently, I received many crash message in iOS9. My Xcode version is 10.1 (10B61), The error stack is like this：

libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8

1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   pthread_kill + 112

2 libsystem_c.dylib abort + 140

3 libsystem_c.dylib basename + 0

4 CoreGraphics  _color_space_get_md5_digest

5 CoreFoundation    CFRelease + 256

6 CoreGraphics  _image_provider_finalize + 144

7 CoreFoundation    CFRelease + 256

8 CoreGraphics  _image_finalize + 88

9 CoreFoundation    CFRelease + 256

10 UIKit    -[UIImage dealloc] + 96

11 CoreFoundation   -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 152

12 UIKit    -[_UIActivityIndicatorViewArtworkItem setImages:] + 80

13 CoreFoundation   ___NSCacheValueRelease + 188

14 libcache.dylib   __value_entry_remove + 116

15 libcache.dylib   __entry_evict + 136

16 libcache.dylib   __evict_last + 104

17 libcache.dylib   __cache_enforce_limits + 96

18 libcache.dylib   ____cache_handle_memory_pressure_event_block_invoke + 88

19 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24

20 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_client_callout + 16

21 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140

22 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112

23 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread + 1092

and

0 libsystem_kernel.dylib    __pthread_kill + 8

1 libsystem_pthread.dylib   pthread_kill + 112

2 libsystem_c.dylib abort + 140

3 libsystem_c.dylib basename + 0

4 CoreGraphics  _CGCMSTransformRelease

5 CoreFoundation    CFRelease + 256

6 CoreGraphics  _color_finalize + 24

7 CoreFoundation    CFRelease + 256

8 UIKit -[UIDeviceRGBColor dealloc] + 40

9 libobjc.A.dylib   (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 508

10 CoreFoundation   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28

11 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 1636

12 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

13 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 180

14 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 204

15 pro  main (main.m:19)

16 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4

It’s only crash on iOS9，does anyone have a similar problem?

I got a device with iOS9 to debug，after I lunched the app，maybe a few minutes later，it will crash。Output message is： Assertion failed: (!space->is_singleton), function color_space_dealloc, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Quartz2D/Quartz2D-1033.4/CoreGraphics/ColorSpaces/color-space.c, line 102.

Comment: Your post doesn't describe what have you done. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details on how to ask questions on SO

Comment: This type of question with vague error messages without refering to your codes is hard for anyone to debug. Good luck bro.

Comment: I got a device with iOS9 to debug，after I lunched the app，maybe a few minutes later，it will crash。Output message is：
Assertion failed: (!space->is_singleton), function color_space_dealloc, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Quartz2D/Quartz2D-1033.4/CoreGraphics/ColorSpaces/color-space.c, line 102.

Comment: There was a bug with Xcode 10.0 building the image catalog for iOS 9, related to color spaces, but I thought that had been fixed in 10.1.  Your first crash is something doing UIKit work on a background thread; that could in turn cause crashes on other threads when those threads are not the real culprit, so I would first try to see if you are doing anything related to a UIActivityIndicatorView on a background thread and fix that.  But your assertion failure could still be the issue.  Does this only happen on 9.0 and 9.1, with 9.2 being OK (a hallmark of the 10.0 image catalog issue)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug somewhere in your code. Looks like it happens when cleaning up an autorelease pool, so tough for you. "Only happens in iOS 9" could be coincidence, or you used a function that is not available in iOS 9. Happy debugging. I'd look where your code uses an UIActivityIndicatorViewArtworkItem.